# Как сделать 10 000 запросов на сервер для node.js сервера?

Tags: javascript, node.js, сервер

Я собрал сервер на Node.js. Сейчас я хочу проверить какое максимальное колличество запросов на страницу можно сделать.
Какие есть инструменты для такого теста ?

Comment: я бы создал другой сервер и в цикле сделал необходимое кол-во запросов к тестируемому

Comment: еще вариант wget + bat\sh

Comment: Я так и сделал, мне хочется статистику собрать  и понимать что происходит с сервером. Скольлко памяти он использует и т д. pm2   с *.mjs не работает. Или у я не знаю как сделать что бы начал работать.

Comment: @Sergey попробуйте [Яндекс.Танк](https://github.com/yandex/yandex-tank). Я сам не настраивал его, но оценить сколько RPS выдерживает сервер + мониторить он умеет.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.
Я очередь поставил, защиту от ddos, мониторингом позднее немного займусь.

Comment: npm пакет autocannon https://www.npmjs.com/package/autocannon

Comment: Консольная утилита wrk https://github.com/wg/wrk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создать простой скрипт файлик, который асинхронно создаст 10000 запросов через цикл, с помощью request, запушь все промисы в массив и дождись их окончания через Promise.all(/*массив с промисами*/)

Comment: Красиво. надо попробовать будет. Я тогда создал цикл с setinterval и смотрел какие запросы исчезают.

Answer (score 1):

Для таких задач отлично подходит Apache Benchmark

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]